# Oracle UCM - Storing and retrieving document under custom directory

Tags: oracle, soap, oracle-ucm, idoc

I am new to Oracle WebCenter Content (Formerly known as Oracle UCM).

I am looking from the integration of UCM to third party application perspective only to retrieve and store the document. I have went through the details about WSDL Generator and also collected the set of SOAP API require to perform check-in and other operations.

We are not going to use UCM directly to store and retrieve the document rather from third party application to store and retrieve the documents (PDF). I have following basic set of questions:

1. Does UCM store my documents under Weblayout directory?
2. How would I store documents under specific directory using Check-in SOAP API? (I.e. If I want to store document under "IT Department" Directory.) Which field I can use to mention the location in wsdl?
3. When I search the document, does it return or can I get the location of the document in search result?

Answer (score 1):

OOTB, UCM stores your original doc in the Native directory and a copy in weblayout - converted to web viewable format if you have IBR enabled. Use a storage rule based on the storage rule metadata field to determine where to store docs based on metadata. See more info [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29542_01/doc.1111/e26692/filestoresystem.htm#CBBEIIFF).

Answer (score 0):

When executing a search, you should receive back a field DocUrl which contains the URL to the content item. However, this URL can break if certain metadata changes (such as dSecurityGroup or dDocType).

A better idea is to use [GET_FILE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/doc.1111/e11011/c04_core.htm#CSSRG2458) and either the dID or the dDocName (and RevisionSelectionMethod).

Additional reading on the FileStoreProvider and how URLs are calculated can be found [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/ecmarch/entry/changes_to_file_store_provider).